# How to get the lowest and highest price for a configurable product to show in category and product page in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am looking for a way to show the lowest price and the highest price of each configurable product on my magento website.

Please could you specify what files I need to change e.g \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml